# rvm remote ruby install using local binary

Tags: ruby, rvm, mount

I'd like to install a pre-compiled ruby using rvm install that I have compiled myself.  I'd like to avoid using rvm mount.

Is there a way to add a local directory to the remote search path for binaries?

Or, is there a trick to adding the precompiled binary bz2 in the archives folder to have it used automatically?

Any hints appreciated.

thanks,
Ean

Answer (score 0):

never mind...providing an explicit local path as a remote path with --binary works fine:
rvm mount -r bin-ruby-2.1.2.tar.bz2 --binary

the binary I was attempting to use before was not created using rvm prepare.